# question about conditional probability formula

Tags: probability

I know that $P(A|B)=0.2, P(A|\bar{B})=0.3, P(B)=0.8$ and I need to find $P(A)$ and $P(B|A)$.

I started with formula: $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} \implies P(A\cap B) = 0.8\cdot 0.2$

Now can I write that $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$ and from here to find $P(A)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

[Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

$$\Pr(A)=\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap \overline{B}) = \Pr(A\mid B)P(B) + \Pr(A\mid \overline{B})\Pr(\overline{B})$$

---

Note: $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is **NOT** equal to $\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$ in general.  This is true if **and only if** $A$ and $B$ are independent events, so your proposed continuation was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

As you did you can also easy calculate $P(A \cap \overline{B})$

Then note that

$$P(A)= P(A \cap B)+   P(A \cap \overline{B})$$